# Find content inside array MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using `Mongoose`with `NodeJS`.

I have these two schemas:

```
var feedSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    users: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }]
    ...
    ...
});
```

and

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    ...
    ...
});
```

I want to find all feeds that contains the `user._id` inside its `users` field.

I'm wondering if `mongoose` has something like this:

```
Feed
.find({
    users : {
        $has : [
            user._id
        ]
    }
})
.exec(function(err, retData) { /* SOMETHING */ });
```

I couldn't find anything like that in the docs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Feed.find( { users: user._id } ).exec(...)
```

Comment: Almost! I've tried `{ users : user._id }` and it worked! Mongoose search inside the array automatically! http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#match-an-array-element